# Recursive Quicksort for a LinkedList

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, linked-list, quicksort

I've been trying to implement a Recursive Quicksort into my algorithm which makes use of LinkedList. However when I run the method, it seems to go on forever even for a small list (of 10 elements), I've been waiting for the method to stop for about 10 minutes.

This is the code in question

```
public static void QuickSort(LinkedList<Contacto> Lista, int ini, int fin){
    Contacto pivote, aux;
    int i, j, comp;


    if (ini<fin){
        pivote = Lista.get(ini);
        i=ini+1;
        j=fin;

        while (i<j){
            while(i<fin && (comp=Lista.get(i).get_name().compareTo(pivote.get_name()))<=0 )
                i++;

            while((comp=Lista.get(i).get_name().compareTo(pivote.get_name()))>0 )
                j--;

            if(i<j){
                aux = Lista.get(i);
                Lista.set(i, Lista.get(j));
                Lista.set(j, aux);
                }
            }
        aux=Lista.get(j);
        Lista.set(j,pivote);
        Lista.set(ini,aux);
        QuickSort(Lista,ini,j-1);
        QuickSort(Lista,j+1,fin);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried to set a break point and trace the code to see what is happening?  I would think if it is taking a long time on a small list, then you probably have an infinite loop or something.

Comment: Its not an answer, but why use QuickSort on a linked list?  From my computer science classes, a merge sort is a much better choice for linked lists.

Comment: @CortAmmon for my school project we need to use both mergesort and quicksort.

Answer (score 0):

As is noted in the comments, the fact that it's taking *ten minutes* to sort a list of ten items is due to a bug somewhere, and I recommend you insert some breakpoints/`println()` statements to get a sense for how your method is proceeding (one at the top of each of your conditionals should be sufficient to show you where it's getting hung up).

That said, inefficiency with very short lists is a known problem with the quicksort algorithm - and, if you think about how the algorithm works, you can see why it's an inherent one. (I can expound on this, but you'll be better off if you figure out why yourself).

A common solution to this issue is having a *cutoff*: When the size of the list becomes smaller than the cutoff size, switch to a simple insertion sort to finish the job. There is a good discussion about this [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/23quicksort/), and a very good example implementation [here](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring02/V22.0102-001/QsortTest.java).

Note the first few lines of the `quicksort()` method in that example:

```
private static void quicksort(Comparable [] a, int left, int right) {
    final int CUTOFF = 3;
    if (right-left+1 < CUTOFF) { // if less than three elements remain: 
         insertionSort(a,left,right);
    else { //quicksort...
```

(note: that first link comes from [the booksite for Algorithms, 4th edition](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu), written by some folks at Princeton. I can't recommend that site highly enough as you're reasoning through the fundamental algorithms)